# Where are desktop icons stored for apps installed from Ubuntu Software?

Tags: shortcuts, desktop-icons

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. Every guide on how to create desktop icons says "go to usr > share > applications", but if the app was installed from Ubuntu Software there's no icon in that folder, so where are they stored? What are all the other directories where they can be stored usually?

Comment: If it's a snap, then it's inside `/snap`. But it won't help you if you want to modify the icons, since snaps are readonly.

Comment: @muru, no, just creating a shortcut on the desktop, thanks, it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [a comment by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391731/ubuntu-software-where-are-desktop-icons-stored#comment2406083_1391731), the OP was able to find the missing icon(s) in `/snap`.

Do a search for *.ico in the file browser, and it will show different places for different icons.